# Why Spring MVC service return method.invoke(target, args) in AopUtils

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, orm, hibernate-criteria

My task is to send a parameter to database and fetch a data according to the parameter.
I debug the code and repository layer will return the result object according to the request.
but in the service layer when it returns it goes to AopUtils.java and called to

```
 try {
            ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible(method);
            return method.invoke(target, args);
        }
```

but not come to the controller which invokes service.  **This is all about java reflection method invoke.**

My service layer is like this.

```
@Override
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly = false)
public AxiPayCustomer unSuccessfulLoginAttempts(AxiPayCustomer axipayCustomer, ServiceContext serviceContext) {

    AxiPayCustomer axiPayCustomer = new AxiPayCustomer();

    if(axipayCustomer.getMsisdn() == null){
        throw new InvalidRequestException(getValidationFailureMessage(REQUESTED_MOBILE_NUMBER_NOT_EXIST,serviceContext));
    }else {
        List<Customer> customer = customerAttemptRepository.unSuccessfulLoginAttempts(axipayCustomer.getMsisdn());

        if(customer == null){
            throw new InvalidRequestException(getValidationFailureMessage(RETURNED_MOBILE_NUMBER_NOT_EXIST,serviceContext));
        }

        Customer axiPayCustomer1 = customer.get(0);
        axiPayCustomer.setAttempts(axiPayCustomer1.getLoginAttempts());
        return axiPayCustomer;
    }
}
```

My repository layer like this.

```
 @Override
public List<Customer> unSuccessfulLoginAttempts(String mobileNumber) {

    Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Customer.class, "c");
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("c.phone1", mobileNumber));
    return criteria.list();

}
```

Controller layer

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/unsuccessful/login/attempts", method = RequestMethod.POST)
   @ResponseBody
    public Response unSuccessfulLoginAttempts(final @RequestBody LoginAttemptsRequest loginAttemptsRequest, HttpServletRequest servletRequest){

       ServiceContext serviceContext = getServiceContext(loginAttemptsRequest, false);
       AxiPayCustomer axiPayCustomer = new AxiPayCustomer();
       BeanUtils.copyProperties(loginAttemptsRequest,axiPayCustomer);

       LoggingAttemptsResponse response = new LoggingAttemptsResponse();

       try{
           AxiPayCustomer customerResponse =  axiPayCustomerService.unSuccessfulLoginAttempts(axiPayCustomer,serviceContext);
           response.setStatus(RequestStatus.SUCCESS.getStatus());
           response.setMessage(customerResponse.getMessage());
           response.setAttempts(customerResponse.getAttempts());
       }catch (Exception e){
           response.setStatus(RequestStatus.FAILURE.getStatus());
       }
     return response;
}
```

My stack-trace like 
[image]

Can anyone explain why i`m getting this kind of problem?

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Please reformat your question.

Comment: problem is i`m not getting the result.only the response failure. i debug .repo returning correct object. but after service layer reflection method invoked.

Comment: Why would you do your own reflection? You're probably messing up some aop stuff? :)

Comment: I dont do anything here. i just wrote the code then run as there is a failure i just debugged.  i posted the stacktrace also please check the question again